# msgbox when all checkboxes empty

Tags: vba, checkbox, warnings, msgbox

I am trying to build a code which will warn the user with a message box if all checkboxes are left empty in my userform.

Any help on how to refer to all checkbox controls in one userform to build out this code would be appreciated.

Below is an example of the code I have tried, but it does not work.

```
Dim Allcheckbox As Variant

Allcheckbox = Array("checkbox1", "checkbox2", "checkbox3", "checkbox4", "checkbox5", "checkbox6")
If Controls(Allcheckbox).Value = False Then
   MsgBox ("Please select a comparison criteria.")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Asher!

I ended up using this code below which provided a solution.

```
Dim x As Integer

    x = 0

    For Each cCont In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "CheckBox" Then
            If cCont.Value = True Then
                x = x + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If x = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Please select a comparison criteria.")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the array and check each value of the checkboxes.  If any are have value = true then we set a boolean to true.  This would be better in a function and you can pass your array and then you can use Exit Function as soon as true is passed.

```
ctrlSelect = False
For Each ctrl In form.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If crtl.value = "True" Then
            ctrlSelect = True
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl

If Not ctrlSelect Then
    MsgBox ("Please select a comparison criteria.")
    Exit Sub
End If
```